# Dynamically Creating Array in Physical Memory

Tags: c, arrays, operating-system, kernel

While creating a physical memory allocator to write a kernel I am trying to create an array of `struct page_frame` where each member of the array is representative of a given physical 4KB block of memory.

[image: Physical to Virtual Mapping and Area for new Array]

Currently the kernel is loaded into physical memory from address `0x000000000` to `physfree`

The remaining blocks from `physfree` to `physEnd` are free blocks.  I would like to create my `struct page_frame` array right after `physfree` and maintain an element in the array for each block in memory from `0` to `physEnd`

The number of indices in this array should thus be `physEnd/4096`.  The problem is, physEnd is not known until runtime, so I am not sure how to dynamically allocate such an array.  Currently, the following does not populate an array of `struct page_frame` because only the first element, `memBlocks[1]` shows up as a proper `struct page_frame` and the rest do not initialize properly.

```
struct page_frame* memBlocks;
memBlocks = (struct page_frame*)kernbase + physfree;

int count = 0;
for(char* i = (char*) 0; i < (char*) ALIGNUP(physEnd)-PAGESIZE; i+=PAGESIZE)
{
    //The new page frame to be placed in array
    struct page_frame insert; 
    insert.used = 1;
    memBlocks[count] = insert;
    count++;
}
```

How can I dynamically create such an array at the address on top of my kernel so that I can keep track of my free physical blocks? I am trying to utilize the pointer to the structs called `memBlocks` and set that to the address right after `kernbase + physfree` in memory (since virtual memory is currently enabled). Then I would like each element of the array to only take up `sizeof(struct page_frame)`.  Am I accessing the elements of `memBlocks` properly by indexing them as `memBlocks[i]`? Or is there a better way to create such an array?

Comment: Not sure why this question is being down voted. If there is an area where it can be improved and you are down voting it please comment.

Comment: What is actually _not working as needed_ in your code example? Please indicate more clearly what the expected result is and what the current result is. Please also add the declaration of `memBlocks`.

Answer (score 1):

Remember that in C, an array of `struct frame` is very very similar to a pointer to a `struct frame`. The simple thing to do, at least if you understand C's pointer arithmetic, is to simply use a pointer to the start of the 'array'.

Given `struct frame *memBlocks` you can access the ith block as `memBlocks + i`

Comment: You can also access it as memBlocks[i].

Comment: Thank you, this is how I have been trying to do this, however after creating all of my structs and stepping through with the debugger, none of them are actually initialized.  I'm not sure if they are being optimized out by the compiler or if the issue is with my code.